# Expose EJB as JAX-RS service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, ejb, jax-rs

I have a problem when i want to expose my EJB Project as JAX-RS service. I've tried to find a solution many times but i've not fixed it. I've succeeded deploy my application but i didn't found my rest service in localhost:4848 => Applications => My_Application. Normally, if a rest service is deployed, there is "Launch" button.

I use glassfish4 and eclipse Java EE.

My EJB Project is like that:

Package ejb: TestSessionBean.java

Package rest: RestTest.java and RestTestApp.java

**TestSessionBean.java**

```
@Path("/peter")
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TestSessionBean {

    public TestSessionBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @GET
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }


}
```

**RestTest.java**

```
@Path("/ep")
public class RestTest {     
    @GET
    public String sayBonjour() {
        return "Bonjour";
    }
}
```

**RestTestApp.java**

```
@ApplicationPath("/test/*")
public class RestTestApp extends Application {  
}
```

I also tried to config my project: Properties => Project Facets => enable JAX-RS (but when i clicked on "Further configuration available", i had "Type: Disable Library Configuration".

I tried localhost:8080/ejbtest/test/peter/ and localhost:8080/ejbtest/test/ep but both didn't work.

But if i create a new Dynamic Web Project all and copy all of my source files in ejbtest into this project. It works! So i think about something to do in eclipse configuration of ejb project. Any solution?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the Glassfish admin console, so I am not sure how it works with REST services, and the launch (Action) link you're referring to, but your `RestTest` works fine, and `TestSessionBean` _would_ work, if it had a method annotated with a Http method (e.g. `@GET`). But getting these two to work, did not produce the `launch` link you are referring to in the Admin console

Comment: Remember `@Path` only makes the class a JAX-RS resource class, but you still need to expose the methods with Http Method annotations, or else none of the methods will match a REST request, and you will get a 404 not found trying to access say a `GET` request from `/peter` as no methods in that class match with a `GET` request. That's just how JAX-RS works

Comment: Thanks for response but i've added a @GET before the function sayHello in TestSessionBean class but it didn't work: localhost:8080/ejbtest/test/peter? Do you think that i need to import or do something with eclipse configuration?

Comment: And my RestTest didn't work too: localhost:8080/ejbtest/test/ep

Comment: Hmmm I don't know. It worked fin for me. Did you look are any exceptions in the server log?

Comment: Did you test it in eclipse? Sorry but i've not found any exeptions...

Comment: No, I haven't set up Glassfish in Eclipse. So I just tested on Netbeans. Put a `index.html` in the web root folder and try to access it via `localhost:8080/ejbtest` and see if it works. Also just confirm, this _is_ a web app you are creating right? Packaged as a `.war`